# Whats best way of getting content from SharePoint to AWS/Azure programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sharepoint

How do we move from sharepoint to AWS estate?

I have found various sources on how to do it in the UI, but nothing programmatically?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Here are UI steps I've found but nothing programmatically - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VW6gqVsvOeQ

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in code using the Graph APIs.  In particular, you'll be looking for the [Working with files in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0) section of the API documentation.

1. Follow these steps to [install the Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation).
2. Follow these steps to [Create an app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app).
3. Follow these steps to [Add a certificate to the app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-self-signed-certificate).
4. Get an auth token in your code.
5. Get the site ID by appending /_api/site/id to the site url e.g. https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/TheSite/_api/site/id
6. Get the list of drives associated with the document libraries on your site.
7. For each drive, get a list of children.
8. Iterate each child recursively to expand through folders and sub folders.
9. Download items.
10. Upload items to AWS.

**Getting an auth token**

```
using Azure.Identity;
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
// Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
// single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
var tenantId = "common";
// Values from app registration
var clientId = "YOUR_APP/CLIENT_ID";
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2("MyCertificate.pfx");
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
// https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientcertificatecredential
var clientCertCredential = new ClientCertificateCredential(
tenantId, clientId, clientCertificate, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientCertCredential, scopes);
```

**Get list of drives**

```
var drives = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Drives
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

**Get root items of a drive**

```
var children = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Root.Children
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

**Get children of items**

```
var children = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Items["{driveItem-id}"].Children
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

**Download files**

```
var stream = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{driveItem-id}"].Content
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```